# Real time audio acquisition using pyAudio (problem with CHUNK size)

Tags: audio, frame, duration, pyaudio, chunks

I am having an issue when I run the code below. The goal is to develop an app that acheives real time sound acquisition. I have set the CHUNK (frame) size to 320 using 16KHz sampling rate, hence, frame duration of 0.02 s. The issue when I record, the result (the content of the variable "many") contains some glitch sounds or noise. When I double the CHUNK, the problem disapears. The value 0.02 depends on the nature of the problem I am trying to resolve. It is required to set to 0.02. Do you have any suggestions?

```
import pyaudio
import struct
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import IPython.display as ipd

CHUNK = int(1*320) 
FORMAT = pyaudio.paFloat32
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 16000

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

chosen_device_index = 1
for x in range(0,p.get_device_count()):
     info = p.get_device_info_by_index(x)
     #print p.get_device_info_by_index(x)
     if info["name"] == "pulse":
          chosen_device_index = info["index"]
          print("Chosen index: ", chosen_device_index)

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input_device_index=chosen_device_index,
                input=True,
                output=False,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK) 

plt.ion()
%matplotlib qt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(0, CHUNK)
data = stream.read(CHUNK)

print(len(data))

data_ = struct.unpack(str(CHUNK) + 'f', data)
line, = ax.plot(x, data_)
ax.set_ylim([-1,1])

many = []
while True:
    data = struct.unpack(str(CHUNK) + 'f', stream.read(CHUNK))
    line.set_ydata(data)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    many= np.concatenate((many, data),axis=None)

ipd.Audio(many,rate = 16000)
```

Comment: The problem here is that handing buffers over to audio hardware is time critical. asking for 2 buffers of 64 numbers inherently has more overhead than asking for a single 128 sample buffer. It looks like you’ve found the limit for the hardware your using with the calculations you are making

Comment: Also, Audio buffer sizes are typically kept to powers of 2, 256 or 512 would be more appropriate sizes

Comment: One question to ask yourself is _keeping the CHUNK size the same, do glitches stop occurring if you remove your `line` and `fig` calls in your `while` loop? If so, then why?_

Comment: Thank you for your comment @fdcpp, I have just tried that. The glishes go away :). I am trying new ways of printing. Any ideas ?

Comment: Now you have more information, you should really scrutinise your question. This is still stack overflow remember. Is this question an accurate reflection of what you’re trying to ask? Try to avoid a quick edit on this, but rather take time to read up on other, similar questions and read around the material. Think hard about what your end goal is and how many different ways you can achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

From the conversation between you can fdcpp, it seems true that the piece of code

```
line.set_ydata(data)
fig.canvas.draw()
fig.canvas.flush_events()
many= np.concatenate((many, data),axis=None)
```

takes more than 0.02 s to run. That's why when the next CHUNK size data comes, your code hasn't been ready to receive it, which causes input overflow.

There are different ways to bypass it. But I agree with fdcpp that the best way to solve this problem is to think about your end goal.
For example, you can separate the processing of receiving audio data from processing the data, i.e., your `line`, `fig` code. One process just receives and stores the audio data, while the other process takes the stored data and draws it.

But please keep in mind that as long as the drawing part takes more than 0.02 s, you cannot achieve "real-time" as you wanted.